# How can I hide the “Page” tab in SP 2010?

Tags: 2010

How can I hide the “Page” tab in SP 2010? I am looking to see if there is any code I can add to a simple webpart.

I do not have access to SP Designer, and many funcations of the site are hidden from me due to IT ownership.  I am the site administrator and am looking for an easy work around.

Thanks for your help and/or ideas!

Comment: Is this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

This link should be a great resource to accomplish this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901454/hide-the-page-button-on-sharepoint